# "The attribute publisher.itemtype has an invalid value"

Tags: schema.org

I'm new to code. I'm trying to add Structured Data code for Google reviews on my contact page:

```
http://www.catnips.co.uk/in-home-mobile-cat-groomer-feline-behaviourist.html
```

I am using the reviews from my Google Maps client reviews.

Testing it in Google Structured Data Testing Tool, it says

> The attribute publisher.itemtype has an invalid value.

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

```
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <meta itemprop="author" content="Anita Kelsey">

    <strong itemprop="itemreviewed">Mobile Cat Grooming</strong> by <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/The+Notting+Hill+Cat+Sitting+and+Cat+Grooming+Company/@51.5254631,-0.2526499,12z/data=!4m10!1m2!2m1!1smobile+cat+grooming!3m6!1s0x4876101c4f92036d:0x8514584f53249c41!8m2!3d51.5180716!4d-0.2036502!9m1!1b1/">Jen Crothers</a><br />

    <strong>My Rating:</strong> <span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><img src="http://www.catnips.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/5-stars-356x73.png" alt="5 stars" width="356" height="73" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-4614" /><meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5" /><meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" /></span>
</div>

<span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">

Anita was absolutely brilliant with my Persian cat Ernie, who was a wriggly customer at times. She skillfully and gently removed the mats on his coat and gave him a very thorough groom. Brilliant, professional and easily a five star service provided from start to finish.
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5" /><meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
```

Comment: The included markup doesn’t give this (or any other) error.

Comment: I found a pretty good answer here: [https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/95983](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/95983)

Answer (score 17):

The error is not in the code you provided in your question body, but rather in the JSON-LD. In the Structured Data Testing Tool, you can click on an error to be taken to the line in the code that caused the error. This helps you identify what caused the problem.

[image]

The error is informing you that the itemtype you provided for the publisher property is invalid. Whilst schema.org does support the type [Person](https://schema.org/Person) for the [publisher](https://schema.org/publisher) property of [Article](https://schema.org/Article), Google does not. **Google only supports [Organization](https://schema.org/Organization)**, not Person, as the type for the publisher property, as mentioned in the [Articles Structured Data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles) page on Google Developers.

[image]

Comment: @Tahnik Then you don't qualify for Google's AMP carousel.

Comment: Your Webhost could be your publisher. Maybe even Namecheap/GoDaddy. You could invent a publisher . --> Tahnik PubCo. Nothing at schema.org states how reputiable the publisher has to be or how strong the webpages ties to that publisher have to be. Just know that Google may use this data for rich snippets.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix error in settings: Yoast SEO > Search Appearance > Knowledge Graph > Choose Company or Person.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Of course you do! You just don't know it yet. ;) Try using this line:

```
"publisher":{"id":"http://www.catnips.co.uk/#organization"},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"baseSalary": {
 "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
 "currency": "EUR",
 "value": {
  "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
  "value": 850,
  "unitText": "MONTH"
 }
}
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer to indicate how it answers the question.